# Saving one to many in core data (iOS)

Tags: ios

I have an object, team.  In this object, I have a property, members, which is a one to many relationship, meaning each team can have many members:

```
extension Team {
    @NSManaged var members: NSSet?
}
```

And in my Member object, I have a one to one relationship, thus completing an inverse relationship w/ the Team object.

```
extension Member {
    @NSManaged var team: Team?
}
```

When I store a Team object, and store multiple member objects `[Member]`, do I need to change the other end of a relationship?  Meaning I have to go to each Member object stored in the members set and set it's team value to the Team that created?  Or will Core Data take care of this for me.  What is the best practice?

Comment: No, inverse relationships are set automatically by Core Data. One of the nicer things it does.

Comment: Thank you.  I saw some snippets of people setting the inverse relationship and was not 100 percent sure.